# Entity Framework 6 only allows 5 attemps when SaveChanges() fails and restart process (concurrency)

Tags: concurrency, entity-framework-6, savechanges

I'm adding new record with entity framework and I need this when I have multiple inserting records and many users on diferent machines at same time (concurrency). So I'm using Catch to restart SaveChanges() process.

In example bellow you can see what I'm triyng to do:

```
Public Sub AdicionaAux(ByRef Attempts As Integer)
            Dim inBlnRepete As Boolean = False
            Try
                Using ctx As New BD.Dinamica.Aplicacao
                    Using trans As DbContextTransaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
                        Try
                            Dim t As tbArtigos = ctx.tbArtigos.FirstOrDefault
                            ctx.tbArtigos.Attach(t)
                            ctx.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Added
                            ctx.SaveChanges() 'FAILS AND GO TO CATCH
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            trans.Rollback()
                            Throw
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch
                inBlnRepete = True 'RepeteFuncaoPorConcorrencia(ex, Tentativas)
                If inBlnRepete And Attempts < 10 Then
                    AdicionaAux(Attempts) 'RESTART PROCESS
                Else
                    Throw
                End If
            End Try
        End Sub
```

**When I'm on 6th time on catch my application crashs and IIS stops.**

**If I'm on Visual Studio debbuging, debugger stops.**

I don't understand why this happens? Why my app crashes and IIS stops?

**It's EF6 Configuration? IIS configuration? SQL configuration?**

In example bellow Using sql I have no problem:

```
Public Sub AdicionaAux(ByRef Attempts As Integer)
        Try
            Dim appServidorSQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServidorSQL")
            Dim appInstanciaSQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("InstanciaSQL")
            Dim appBDEmpresa As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BDEmpresa")
            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Server=" & appServidorSQL & "\" & appInstanciaSQL & ";User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=" & appBDEmpresa & ";")
                connection.Open()
                Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
                Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction")
                command.Connection = connection
                command.Transaction = transaction
                Try
                    command.CommandText = _
                      "Insert into tbDestinos (Codigo, Descricao, Ativo, Sistema, DataCriacao, UtilizadorCriacao) VALUES ('POR', 'Description',1,1,getdate(),'xxx')"
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    transaction.Commit()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    transaction.Rollback()
                    Throw
                End Try
            End Using
        Catch
            AdicionaAux(Attempts)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any help?